# Confusing declaration and initializer

Tags: c++, pointers, initializer-list

This declaration is very confusing:

```
char* q {new char[1024]{}}; // q[i] becomes 0 for all
```

Is this a “pointer to a `char` array”, or an “array of `char` pointers”?

I think that `new char[1024]{}` is initializing a `char` array of 1024 elements each having a value of `0`.

So this is the same as:

```
char* q = [0,0,....] // until 1024
```

Correct?

Comment: `char *q` is a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`q` is a pointer to a `char`.   In other words, it is of type `char *`.

It is initialised using the expression `new char[1024]{}` which dynamically allocates an array of `char` and zero-initialises them.    If this fails, an exception will be thrown.

`q` will point to the first `char` in the dynamically allocated array.   It is not an array.

It is not the same as

> char* q = [0,0,....] // until 1024

since that is invalid syntax.  It is also not equivalent to

```
char* q = {0,0,....}; //  1024 zeros in initialiser
```

since `q` is a pointer and cannot be initialised to a set of values.    It is closer in (net) effect to

```
char *q = new char[1024];     //  dynamically allocates chars uninitialised here
std::fill(q, q + 1024, '\0');
```

except that the characters are initialised to zero, rather than being first uninitialised and then overwritten with zeros (and, of course, it is up to the compiler how it initialises the characters).

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation! I understand now that `p` simply points to the address of the first element.  Is it correct to say that **1024** `8-bit pieces of memory` (not sure of the correct terminology) have been reserved on the heap and have been initialized to `0`?

Comment: @SamHammamy the (overly) correct thing to say would be that "memory with a size of at least 1024 addressable memory units has been allocated with operator new". `at least` because the compiler may allocate more memory for arrays, `addressable memory units` because `char` defines the smallest addressable memory unit and counting in bits is secondary. `operator new` because the heap is not recognized by the standard. On a normal machine, this would be the same as what you said though

Comment: @SamHammamy - I wouldn't say that is quite correct. The `new`-expression dynamically allocates memory of size equal to `1024` (more strictly `1024` times the size of a `char`, but the standard defines `sizeof(char)` to be `1`). As WorldSEnder` noted, the implementation may allocate more (e.g. round up to multiple of a system-dependent "block size") but your program cannot rely on that.  The "heap" is/was an implementation detail of memory management of some (older) systems, and does not reflect what the standard requires or other systems do.  Lastly, a `char` may be more than 8 bit.

Answer (score 28):

```
char* q {new char[1024]{}};
```

is equal to

```
char* q = new char[1024]{};
```

which in turn is equal to

```
char* q = new char[1024] { 0, 0, 0, 0 /* 1020 more zeros */ }
```